# Db2 with Docker: How to resolve error from bash script?

Tags: docker, db2

I have a syntax problem - Mac Mojave- starting a docker bash script:

```
docker run -h db2server \
    --name db2server_fp4 \
    --restart=always p 50000:50000  \
    --env-file ${HOME}/db2devc.env_list \ 
     ${HOME}/db2devc:/database \
    store/ibmcorp/db2_developer_c:11.1.4.4-x86_64
```

gives this error:

```
JMB:~ Juergen$ ./db2docker2.sh
Unable to find image 'p:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for p, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
./db2docker2.sh: line 6: /Users/Juergen/db2devc:/database: No such file or directory
```

Comment: P.S. the db2 image was downloaded - pulled - before

Comment: Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake in your docker run command. There is missing hyphen before the p and docker recognizes it as the image name.

There also seems to be a missing -v before what looks like a volume mount.

Try with the following command:

```
docker run -h db2server \
  --name db2server_fp4 \
  --restart=always -p 50000:50000 \
  --env-file ${HOME}/db2devc.env_list \
  -v ${HOME}/db2devc:/database \
  store/ibmcorp/db2_developer_c:11.1.4.4-x86_64
```